# Want data from table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have table data like this

```
id id1  name
1  1    test1
1  1    test1
1  2    test2
2  1    test1
2  2    test2
3  1    test1
3  2    test2
3  2    test2
```

now from table i want the data as below
like 
for id = 1 order by id1 asc the first name = test1
so i want the first two row

```
id id1  name
1  1    test1
1  1    test1
```

not third row

For id=2 order by id1 asc the first name = test1
so i want first row as test1 has assign only ones for id=2

```
id id1  name
2  1    test1
```

And for id=3 same as id=2

Please suggest me how can get the perticlur value for ID , because the scenerio is differnt for ID=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` to get the first ranked rows, including duplicates, for each id.

```
select * from (
    select *, dense_rank() over (partition by [id] order by [id2]) as ranking
    from [table]
) as t
where ranking = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much..it is woking

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you just want `select * from [tablename] where id1 = 1`, but I might be wrong. I find the question a bit, well, vague...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
select * from [table] where id = 1 order by id1
```

I think the point is that you can use one column in the where clause, and a different column in the order by clause. that's no problem.

But I'm not sure you could actually have the data table you describe, because the first two rows are identical (how can SQL tell them apart? Or more technically, there'd be a primary key violation)?

Comment: hello ,'test1' is nox fix as data, it should be any. I has just given example.

Comment: and also want for all ID not for only one id

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [table] where id = 1 and name like "test1" order by id1
```

Comment: hello ,'test1' is nox fix as data, it should be any